# stubhub API 'Search for events' Issue

Tags: python

I'm using Python and its requests module to pull data from Stubhub.
api url is api.stubhub.com, and headers include my api key.
Other API references we've called seem to work so far, but this one is giving me errors:

```
def get_event_from_type(search_term):
     url = api_url + '/search/catalog/events/v3'
     query = {'q': search_term, 'status': 'active'}
     r = requests.get(url, params=query, headers=headers)
     return r
```

https://developer.stubhub.com/store/site/pages/doc-viewer.jag?category=Search&api=EventSearchAPIv3&endpoint=searchforeventsv3&version=v3
We get 401 Error, but we seem to be using the correct format.
We tried example like search_term='Boston'